# How to enable debugging for website project in visual studio 2013 so I can test my pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a solution containing a website project on visual studio 2013 with .aspx/.aspx.cs pages. I want to be able to debug my pages so they appear in a web browser for testing.

Could someone explain how I do this, I want to create a precompiled web site file that I can target through the .sln file i think... Just not sure how i go about doing this, I have provided the current .sln file in visual studio below which includes incorrect settings that need to be changed such as http://localhost:63172 as the web project no longer resides on a server.. I just want to debug from my local machine please help!

[visual studio error image https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfxEC.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC72l.jpg)

I get this error when I try to debug my pages with f11, any idea how i go about editing the .sln file and setting up the correct target paths etc?

[sln file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC72l.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should understand that we are unable to reach the web page produced by your local VS2013 web server (apparently, the link you've posted doesn't work).

In terms of web project/site debugging in VS: go to the code behind of your `default.aspx`, set the break points and execute it step-by-step (using F11 button). Also, in Web.config file set `compilation debug="true`". Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach to the browser process for a WEB SITE:

1. Start a browser on the site.
2. Attach to that process (browser);

You can attach the Visual Studio debugger to a running process on a local or remote computer. After the process is running, click Debug / Attach to Process, or press CTRL+ALT+P, to start the Attach to Process dialog box.

Ref:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx